# Should an OPTIONS request ever return 429?

Tags: javascript, api, http-status-codes, http-options-method

Should an `OPTIONS` request ever return a `429`?

The problem is really that a Browser client (js) can not detect the `429` correctly when returned from an `OPTIONS` request. So I'm leaning towards only returning `429` for non `OPTIONS` requests.

What is best practise here?

Comment: Nothing in the HTTP spec forbids returning 429 from an OPTIONS request.

Comment: The question is legitimate: browsers may not handle well error codes on OPTIONS requests even if such codes are allowed by the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPTIONS` is a [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). Typically the response is static with just a few headers. So sending the real response is no more strain on the server than responding with 429 (Too Many Requests). If browsers have trouble with it, it would make sense to always send the real response for OPTIONS, and let the immediately-following actual request get the error.

Comment: `Typically the response is static with just a few headers.` - I did not know that. It makes a lot of sense though. I'll remove the 429 logic from the `OPTIONS` request. Accepted!